# I need to pass a concatenated string as a web api Url

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I am developing a PCL Project in Xamarin .I need to pass the IP Address of the device dynamically in the web api Url.
My Code is as below:

**In the code behind:**

```
string IpAdd = txtIP.Text;

 IPAddress = "http://" + IpAdd + ":8124/api/Items/";

 MainViewModel.FinalIPAddress = IPAddress;
```

**In my MainViewModel**

```
public static string FinalIPAddress { get; set; }

 public static readonly string WebServiceUrl = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(FinalIPAddress);
```

But I am unable to get through this. The below exception gets thrown.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Net.Http.Phone.ni.DLL
Additional information: An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
```

How to go about with this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what specific line is throwing the exception, and what specific argument are you passing that causes it?  Why are you URLEncoding an IP address?

Comment: public static readonly string WebServiceUrl = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(FinalIPAddress); - this is the line exactly that throws this exception. And I am passing the variable "FinalIPAddress" from the code behind to my view model.. "FinalIPAddress" is the conacatenated string which includes the IPAddress that the user inputs.

Comment: WebServiceUrl is going to be null when this class is instantiated. Why not set the value in the FinalIPAddress property?

Comment: @JoshuaPoling - Can u pls show me how to do the same in my code?

Comment: @user1508599 Are you using HttpClient?

Comment: @Madhav Shenoy - Yes. I am using HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking your WebServiceUrl in the model implementation looks strange. Models should be thin. Why not call the UrlEncode on the model's FinalIPAddress at the point in time you are trying to use the WebServiceUrl and remove that from the model entirely?

Regardless, when the model is created it likely doesn't have a value for FinalIPAddress until you assign it, so it's blank and you get the exception I'm thinking. If you want to do this approach, why not make it a static string function instead of a variable which returns the result of UrlEncode(FinalIPAddress). Then when you call it, likely after you have populated FinalIPAddress, it's created in real time and you have the same result.

Also, traditionally in an api, you should have access natively to the client's ip address that is making the request from the request itself and the user agent. That may be a leaner approach to consider.

Edit: As requested, the smallest code change which would accomplish this would be removing the

```
public static readonly string WebServiceUrl = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(FinalIPAddress);
```

and replacing with a static method you could call

```
public static string WebServiceUrl() 
{
   return System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(FinalIPAddress);
}
```

Then use the method call like you would any model variable, MainViewModel.WebServiceUrl(), and just treat it like a string.

There are many ways to accomplish what you are trying to do, and some are arguably much better practice. It's worth reading up on, but for now this small change would make your code functional.

Comment: can u pls show me in code how to go about with ur suggestion @Nard Dog?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will solve your issue. Normally you wouldn't have the base address change if you're only pointing to your api, but I'm not sure what the end goal here is.

**Model**

Since you're planning on hard coding the scheme and path you only need to set the base address from the users input.

```
public class Model
{
    public string BaseAddress { get; set; }
    public string Scheme { get { return "http://"; } }
    public string Path { get { return ":8124/api/Items"; } }

    public string WebServiceURL {
        get {
            return Scheme + BaseAddress + Path;
        }
    }
}
```

**Implementation**

I created a test Entry with a submit button here.

```
private Entry _urlEntry = new Entry { Placeholder = "url" };
private Button _submit = new Button { Text = "Submit" };
private Model _model;

public BackPage()
{
   Content = new StackLayout
   {
      Children = { _urlEntry, _submit }
   };
      _submit.Clicked += Submit_Clicked;
 }
```

**Button Event**

You don't have to actually instantiate your model here I just don't need it for anything else in the example.

```
 private void Submit_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
    var text = _urlEntry?.Text;

    if(text.Length > 0)
    {
       _model = new Model {  BaseAddress = text };
       MakeRequest(_model.WebServiceURL);
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error", "Entry field is empty", "ok");
    }
  }
```

**Make Request Here**

```
 private void MakeRequest(string url)
 {

 }
```

**Output**

Here you can see once you set the Model.BaseAddress you will have the correct "FinalIPAdress" you're looking for.

[image: Example running program]
[image: url after setting baseaddress from input]

Answer (score 0):

public static readonly string WebServiceUrl

remove the 'readonly', which should work in your case.

Comment: Wouldn't WebServiceUrl be null when you try and access it? WebServiceUrl  is an instance variable so it's not going to update the value based on the model.